# In magento 2.3 I'm not able to remove white space around gallery image on product detail page

Tags: product, magento2.3

I have installed **magento 2.3** version, and I'm not able to remove frame from fotoroma image.

I have tried to **override/extend** `view.xml` from parent theme and tried options like `<frame>false</frame>`, but that also didn't work.

Here is my extended view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">
    <media>
        <images module="Magento_Catalog">
            <image id="product_page_image_large" type="image" />
            <image id="product_page_image_medium" type="image">
                <width>518</width>
                <height>712</height>
                <frame>false</frame>
            </image>
            <image id="gift_messages_checkout_small_image" type="small_image">
                <width>368</width>
                <height>275</height>
            </image> 
            <image id="mini_cart_product_thumbnail" type="thumbnail">
                <width>368</width>
                <height>275</height>
            </image>
            <image id="product_thumbnail_image" type="thumbnail">
                <width>368</width>
                <height>275</height>
            </image>
            <image id="rss_thumbnail" type="thumbnail">
                <width>368</width>
                <height>275</height>
            </image>
            <image id="sendfriend_small_image" type="small_image">
                <width>368</width>
                <height>275</height>
            </image>
        </images>
    </media>
</view>
```

Comment: Update the code of view.xml file into question.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya Updated my question, Please check.

Comment: @Gopal Garva, add screenshot please

Answer (score 1):

try to add

```
<frame>false</frame>
```

into `product_thumbnail_image` like this

```
<image id="product_thumbnail_image" type="thumbnail">
                <width>368</width>
                <height>275</height>
                <frame>false</frame>
            </image>
```

Run caching, deploy command and check.

Comment: this does not solve the problem. In my case the white frame is still there (after having flushed image cache of course). the only way I found to remove white frame is to put 0 instead of false in the view.xml. Is there any better way to handle also the false value in view.xml?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is the frame parameter in view.xml as mentionned in Dhiren answer is not meant for this. Its documentation states :

> If set to true, images are not cropped. Default value: true. Applied
>   only if aspect_ratio is set to true.

cf: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-images.html#view_xml_structure

What I found out was just set a max-height to div `fotorama__stage` with what you set up in view.xml solves it :

For instance if view.xml is setup like this :

```
<image id="product_page_image_medium" type="image">
  <width>518</width>
  <height>712</height>
  <frame>false</frame>
</image>
```

Setting a max-height for fotorama__stage to the same height set up in view.xml did the trick :

```
.fotorama__stage {
    max-height:712px;
}
```